# How to customize alert schemas for Azure Logic Apps

Tags: triggers, schema, alert, azure-logic-apps, azure-monitor

I have this Logic App that usually runs once the same time everyday. I need an email to be sent to a set of recipients every time the app runs. For this, I created an action group and added the email addresses of the recipients with the Notification type Email/SMS/Push/Voice. Here, there's an option called "Enable the common alert schema."
I then saved that Action Group. Then I created an alert rule for the condition "Triggers Fired" so that the alert would be activated whenever the trigger is fired, and added that action group to this alert rule.

I am now getting the alert as an email, but I need only a set of information to be received when the trigger fires. When I Enable the common alert schema option, it sends an alert with a template. When I Disable it, I still cannot edit the alert schema there. How should I edit the alert schema to contain only the information I need?

Answer (score 0):

Using logic app compose action you can customize alert schema.

I have reproduced issue from my side and below are steps I followed,

1. Created Logic app as shown below,
   [image]
2. Configured this logic app to an action group.
3. In logic app, Using compose action formed a customized schema as shown below,
   [image]
4. Without compose action the schema is in below format,
   [image]
5. With Compose action the schema is in below format,
   [image]